# RSA encoding on JavaScript(frontend) and python(backend)

Tags: javascript, python, rsa

Below are my python code(function check_key_pair_match) and javascript code(function checkKeyPairMatch). I used the same input
(for example:
public_key_pem(string):

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDeyL0AR29yRTpbu+IuqLCJUCAq
2ZQG/bHUjNNOb6H7awditdQEuiRVwuXqx1jrzA5ReoQBhpiVVtqX82Qa0t2QnEKi
uNZdTNuEiofJ9SkWC1OEFi+M/rtfzO1r/9Efy1j1nbLeLlcspPKovuQTPLpe6O8a
O1HMxNHsGiFFRFKIVwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

plaintext(string):
abcd
) but their outcomes(encoded string) were not the same.

```py
import base64
from random import seed
from pydantic import BaseModel
# from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
# from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
# from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
# import os, time
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
def check_key_pair_match(public_key_pem: string, plaintext: string):
    # Encode the plaintext to bytes using UTF-8
    plaintext_bytes = plaintext.encode('utf-8')

    # Encrypt the plaintext with the public key
    public_key = RSA.import_key(public_key_pem)
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)
    encrypted_data = cipher.encrypt(plaintext_bytes)
    # Print the base64-encoded string
    encrypted_data_base64 = base64.b64encode(encrypted_data)
    print("public_key:", public_key_pem)
    print("Plaintext:", plaintext_bytes)
    print("Encrypted:", encrypted_data_base64)
```

```js
        //javascript
        async function checkKeyPairMatch(publicKeyPem, plaintext) {
            // Encode the plaintext to bytes using UTF-8
            const encoder = new TextEncoder();
            const plaintextBytes = encoder.encode(plaintext);
        
            // Import the public key
            const publicKey = await importPublicKey(publicKeyPem);
        
            // Encrypt the plaintext with the public key
            const encryptedData = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
                {
                    name: "RSA-OAEP",
                },
                publicKey,
                plaintextBytes
            );
        
            // Convert the encrypted data to a Base64-encoded string
            const encryptedBase64 = arrayBufferToBase64(encryptedData);
        
            // Print the Base64-encoded string
            console.log("public_key:", publicKeyPem);
            console.log("Plaintext:", plaintextBytes);
            console.log("Encrypted:", encryptedBase64);
        }
        
        async function importPublicKey(publicKeyPem) {
            // Extract the base64-encoded part from the PEM format
            const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
            const pemFooter = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
            const pemContents = publicKeyPem
                .replace(pemHeader, "")
                .replace(pemFooter, "")
                .trim();
        
            // Convert base64-encoded string to Uint8Array
            const binaryDerString = atob(pemContents);
            const binaryDer = new Uint8Array(binaryDerString.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < binaryDerString.length; i++) {
                binaryDer[i] = binaryDerString.charCodeAt(i);
            }
        
            // Import the public key
            const publicKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
                "spki",
                binaryDer,
                {
                    name: "RSA-OAEP",
                    hash: "SHA-256",
                },
                true,
                ["encrypt"]
            );
        
            return publicKey;
        }
        
        // Helper function to convert ArrayBuffer to Base64
        function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
            const binary = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            const base64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, binary));
            return base64;
        }
```

I have asked chatGPT and it said their logic and encoding method are the same, but their outcomes(the encoded string) are not the same. Now I'm confused couldn't know the reason. I hope their logit are exactly the same.

Comment: RSA encryption with OAEP (but also PKCS#1 v1.5) is *not* deterministic, i.e. repeated encryption of the same plaintext with the same public key provides different ciphertexts. RSA without padding (textbook RSA) is deterministic, but this is insecure and is therefore not used in practice.

Comment: You can find many posts on the web that discuss the different padding variants with regard to security, e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59017).

Comment: Note that your codes are incompatible because Python uses the default value for the OAEP and MGF1 digests, namely SHA-1 (see [`PKCS1_OAEP.new()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/oaep.html#Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP.new)), while the JavaScript code explicitly specifies SHA-256 (for both digests).